# How to disable cache for specific images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular UI to route to different states. My Home-page is loaded with an image background applied to it and after successful login, the login-page should load without any image background.

The problem is when login page is loaded for the first time it is loading the image background as in the home page even though the script tags are placed separately in login page itself and when I refresh the page it doesn't load the background image.

It is because of caching? or do I have to use any tool like grunt or requirejs to load my script tags dynamically?

The image is loaded using backstrech JS inside `script.js file` like this:

`$.backstretch("assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg");`

UI-view:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div ui-view="header" ng-if="$state.current.name != 'Home'"></div>
        <div ng-class="{'col-xs-3': $state.current.name != 'Home'}">
            <div ui-view="sidebar" ng-if="$state.current.name != 'Home'"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-class="{'col-xs-9': $state.current.name != 'Home'}">
            <div ui-view="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div ui-view="footer" ng-if="$state.current.name != 'Home'"></div>
```

Login page:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Login-page</h3>
    </div>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am trying to replace the script tag with new script tag + date time to prevent caching of image. I achieved it till here. How do I apply it to directive

```
myApp.directive('preventCaching', function () {

    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: false,
        replace: false,
        translude: true,
        link: link,
//        template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'
    };
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.scriptFile = element.find('script')[0];
        scope.src = scope.scriptFile.src;
        scope.srcLastSlashIndex = scope.src.lastIndexOf('/');
        scope.fileName = scope.src.substring(scope.srcLastSlashIndex + 1, scope.src.length);
        scope.preFileName = scope.src.substring(0, scope.srcLastSlashIndex + 1);
        scope.replacedFileName = scope.preFileName + scope.fileName + '?' + new Date().getMilliseconds();
        console.log("replacedFileName: " + scope.replacedFileName);
    }
});
```

Directive inside page:

```
<prevent-caching>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</prevent-caching>
```

Comment: Could you not do the same with a CSS class for the background image and an `ng-class`?

Comment: @DanielDawes the background image is getting loaded using a `javascript(script.js) + backstrechJs(jquery.backstretch.min.js)` and this is the line it is loading it: `$.backstretch("assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg");`